# Need missing values from two sheets, my copy functions all work fine

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote some code in VBA to bring back values missing from two sheets. When I entered just the index match function into the code, the code ran great. But I wanted to bring back only values that were missing instead of all values and N/A's so I wrote a function adding in an extra if statement and an `ISNA`. When I run the function in excel it works, but when I add it to my code it fails.

I have tried reformatting it but it seems to be in the code appropriately.

```
Sub IndexMatch_Formula()
    ' Index Match Formula

    Dim Wa As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Worksheets("Analysis").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Wa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis")

    With Wa
        'C
        .Range("C2").Formula = "=IF(ISNA(IF(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,B:B,0))=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,B:B,0)),"",A2))=TRUE,A2,"")"
        .Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("Analysis").Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
    End With
End Sub
```

I expect the code to bring back only missing values from two sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 2x`"` around your double-quote:

```
.Range("C2").Formula = "=IF(ISNA(IF(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,B:B,0))=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,B:B,0)),"""",A2))=TRUE,A2,"""")"
```

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks. Always seems to be something small like that.